# How to determine horizontal scroll position in vim

Tags: vim

In the below vim window represented by *`visible area`*, how do I get the horizontal position of `X`, relative to `Y`, from a function?

```
Y------------------------+
1 File contents          |
|                        |
|   +-X--------------+   |
|   |4|              |   |
|   |5| Visible area |   |
|   |6|              |   |
|   +-+--------------+   |
$    ^                   |
+----|-------------------+
     \
       line numbers
```

For example, the *vertical* position of `X` relative to `Y` is four, as in the window is scrolled four rows down.  I can get this as a zero-based index with `line("w0") - 1`.

I how do I determine how many columns rightwards the window is scrolled at a given moment?  I've tried `virtcol(".") - wincol()` but that alone is slightly off if the cursor is over a double-width character.

Comment: In the most basic example, suppose I just want to display something like `Showing columns 3 - 83 of 430` in the status line to indicate that there's hidden data to the left or right of the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution without modifying the cursor position:

```
winsaveview().leftcol
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have number column width use `max([len(line('$')), &numberwidth])+1`.

<s>What does “horizontal position” mean? `wincol()` is horizontal position in the window, `col(".")` is byte offset from the start of the line, `strchars(getline('.')[:(col('.')-1)])` is the number of unicode codepoints from the start of the line, `len(split(getline('.')[:(col('.')-1)], '.\@='))` is the number of characters from the start of the line.</s>

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate that vim doesn't have a more direct way to get this, but the following will work

```
let cursor_pos = getpos('.')
normal g0
let scroll_x = col('.')
setpos('.', cursor_pos)
```

The trick is the `g0` motion, which moves the cursor the left of the window, and from there we can get the current cursor column.